# Error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *'

Tags: visual-c++

Below is the insert function in VC++.
I am getting this error when I change the char to string data type to read the value of amount variable in the below code.

```
static void Insert(t_analysis* analysis)    
{    
 _bstr_t strunitId;    
 _bstr_t strGdt=time(0);    
_bstr_t strvalue;   
    std::string str;
std::string commandStr = "insert into table1(unitid,g_time_dte_1,h_1,n_1,ch_1,co_1,im_1,ve_1,er_1) Values(123,'" + strGdt +"',";
    char tempBuf[50];
for (int j = 0; j < analysis->ubPeaksIntTab;j++ )
{   
    sprintf(tempBuf, "%d", (analysis->peak + j)->amount);//here it takes the adrress of amount but not the value of amount variable.
    str += commandStr + tempBuf;
    if(j!=analysis->ubPeaksIntTab-1)
       commandStr += ",";
}

commandStr += ")";
_ConnectionPtr pConn = NULL;

try
{       
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = pConn.CreateInstance((__uuidof(Connection)));
    _bstr_t strCon("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Dataq Source=MYPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=keerth;User ID=sa;Password=password;Connect Timeout=30;");

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Error instantiating Connection object\n");

    }

    hr = pConn->Open(strCon,"sa","password",0);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Error Opening Database object using ADO _ConnectionPtr \n");

    }

    //Execute the insert statement
    pConn->Execute(commandStr.c_str(), NULL,adExecuteNoRecords);
    pConn->Close();
}
catch(_com_error &ce)
{
    printf("Error:%s\n",ce.ErrorMessage());
    pConn->Close();
}
}
```

Whenever I run this getting the Error. Then I changed  the `char tempbuf[50];` to `std::string str1;`.
Now it is showing:

```
Error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *;
```

The amount variable contains the float value.
How can I copy the float value assign it to string variable?

Comment: why c tag? `::` is a syntax error in C, `string`, and `try` are ordinary identifiers! C tag removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing C++ with C standard library functions.

You should use the C++ primitives. See [StringStreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main () {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "hello world";
  ss << 45;
  ss << std::endl;
  std::string foo = ss.str();
  std::cout << foo;
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

If you want the same logic in C: The type std::string is not a C type, the standard string type of C is `char *` and `const char *` for immutable strings.

The functions that you want to look at are then: `strncat` (concatenate strings) and the safer `snprintf`.

Comment: Hi Alex,thanks for the reply... I want the same logic in C not in C++ actually.I am using vsiual studio VC++ compiler to run the application.Char is the only thing the VC++ recognized.so i tried declared it as char* str; but it showing undecaled identifier.So checked in VC++ string.

Comment: Here my program is in C.    

     char* str;
     const char* commandstr="insert into table1(unitid,g_time_dte_1,h_1,n_1,ch_1,co_1,im_1,ve_1,er_1) Values(123,'" + strGdt +"',";

 sprintf(str, "%d", (analysis->peak + j)->amount);// here it shows error while running the code

 Error:Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'str' is being used without being initialized

 same Initial code.

Comment: that is because char * is a pointer to char. and you need to allocate memory on the heap for this to work. or you use stack allocated buffers like #define BUFFER_SIZE 256 char str[BUFFER_SIZE];

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::stringstream` (you'll need to include `<sstream>`):

```
float amount = 3.14159;
std::stringstream ss;

ss << amount;

std::string tempbuf = ss.str();
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply...it works fine when i run this program alone. but i want to implement it in C..actaully my application was in C not C++.am using VC++ compiler to run the program.I tird using the char* str instead of std::string.it was showing undeclared identifier for char* str;

Answer (score 2):

sprintf needed char* but not std::string

```
int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );
```

you can use ostringstream instead

```
ostringstream oss1;
oss1 << (analysis->peak + j)->amount;
oss1.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not use sprintf for stl string, use ostringstream instead:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/// ...

ostringstream strstr;
strstr << (analysis->peak + j)->amount;
str += str.str()
```